# UICollectionView doesn't scroll to bottom

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uikit

I have an UICollectionView built programatically that doesn't allow me to scroll to the last item in it.

[image]

Here is how I set it up

```
private let collectionView: UICollectionView = UICollectionView(
        frame: .zero,
        collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { sectionIndex, _ -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
            return WorkoutListViewController.createSectionLayout(section: sectionIndex)
        })
```

```
private static func createSectionLayout(section: Int) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        // item
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)
            )
        )
        item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 14, leading: 0, bottom: 14, trailing: 0)
        
        // group
        let verticalGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
            layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
                widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                heightDimension: .absolute(123)
            ),
            repeatingSubitem: item,
            count: 1
        )
        
        // section
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: verticalGroup)
        return section
    }
```

```
private func configureCollectionView() {
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        collectionView.register(
            WorkoutListCollectionViewCell.self,
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier: WorkoutListCollectionViewCell.identifier
        )
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }
```

I tried modifying the height by giving it a very large number (e.g 2000) and nothing changed. I also tried adding the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol to add the

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
    }
```

function and return the `CGSize` of my item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your collection view is hiding behind the TabBar, So try to set the ContentInset of your collection view based on the bottom TabBar height.

Example:

```
collectionView.contentInset = .init(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: bottomHeight, right: 0.0)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you didn't set the constraint for the bottom of the collection view.

Try to get border for the collection view and see where collection view is ending.

constraint for the collection view bottom should be top of the bottom bar...

though above answer of Natarajan is working but this is not the main cause of the issue. That is just a solution to avoid real problem.